# How inject Map<> or Set<> (dagger 2 multibindings) with Toothpick

Tags: android, dependency-injection, toothpick-di

Dagger 2 has the ability to injecting set or map with multibindings.
How to do it in Toothpick

for example i want 
`@Inject constructor(val map: Map<String, ISyncRepository>)`

Answer (score 1):

it might be like:

```
   @Binds
   @IntoMap
   @TheMapKey(“your key”)
   abstract fun getSyncRepository() : ISyncRepository
```

Look at the following 2 samples

https://google.github.io/dagger/multibindings.html

https://blog.kotlin-academy.com/understanding-dagger-2-multibindings-viewmodel-8418eb372848

for

```
@Inject constructor(

     private val creators: Map<Class<out ViewModel>, @JvmSuppressWildcards 
         Provider<ViewModel>>

)
```

using:

```
@Binds
@IntoMap
@ViewModelKey(UserViewModel.class)
abstract ViewModel bindUserViewModel(UserViewModel userViewModel);
```

Comment: question is -  **How to do it in Toothpick**